# JSON.NET ignores ISerializable on collection type object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a wrapped list that looks like this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
public class OrderManager : IEnumerable<Order>, ISerializable
{
    public OrderManager()
    { }

    private List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

    public void AddOrder(OrderInfo orderInfo)
    {
        // do the work of making an order object from an OrderInfo.
        // Add the new order object to the private list of orders
        // orders.Add(order);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Order> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return orders.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return orders.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public OrderManager(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // do custom serialization work here (never gets hit)
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // do custom serialization work here (never gets hit)
    }
}
```

I include a field instance in a customer class like this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    { }

    private OrderManager _orders
        = new OrderManager();
    public OrderManager Orders
    {
        get { return _orders; }
        set { _orders = value; }
    }
}
```

I can serialize a customer but the `ISerializable` interface on `OrderManager` is ignored. If I remove the `JsonObject` attribute from the `OrderManager` (probably what is preventing `ISerializable` from being used) the `OrderManager` is treated as an array and the `ISerializable` interface is still ignored.

I tried using `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable`:
[JSON.NET cannot deserialize a wrapped collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488351/json-net-cannot-deserialize-a-wrapped-collection)

Since my wrapped collection is of type `Order` and my `AddOrder` method takes in `OrderInfo`, it doesn't really work to expose `ICollection<Order>`. Either way, the `ISerializable` interface was ignored.

Are there any workarounds?

*Update*

Just to clarify I do have IgnoreSerializableInterface set to false.

```
private JsonSerializer GetSerializer()
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    serializer.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;

    var contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(true);
    contractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false;
    contractResolver.IgnoreSerializableInterface = false;

    serializer.ContractResolver = contractResolver;

    serializer.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
    serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

    return serializer;          
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the instantiation of `_orders` into the `Customer` constructor?

Comment: Just tried that. With and without the JsonObject attribute on OrderManager, ISerializable was still ignored.

Comment: Just curious if you add the `[Serializable]` attribute and make the constructor for `[JsonObject()]` empty.  I was reading up on this a bit on the JSON.NET doc site, and I'm wondering if there's a conflict that's happening.  The `Serializable` attribute has the same effect as `JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)`, according to the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer might be late but:

This is because it checks for inheritance of `IEnumerable` before checking for inheritance of `ISerializable` so it will use the Enumerable interface to pull objects out first.

You can override this behavior by implementing your own contract resolver inheriting from `DefaultContractResolver` with this override:

```
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (typeof(ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
            return CreateISerializableContract(objectType);

        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
```

Preferably with some better logic, but this at the root will cause objects that implement `ISerializable` and `IEnumerable` to use the ISerializable implementation first.